# Are there 'private' server methods in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to stop a Client calling a Server Method from the browser console?

I gather from the [Unofficial Meteor FAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#what-are-best-practices-for-security) that there isn't.  I just wanted to check if that's definitely the case - the FAQ isn't really specific.  I mean are there no 'private' methods?

Comment: **Anything** that a client can do can also be done from the browser console. That's why you should never trust the client.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In meteor the 'methods' described by Meteor.methods can all be called from the client. In this sense there aren't `private` methods because the purpose of the RPC call is for the client to make the call.

If you want a 'private' method you could use an ordinary JavaScript method. If you define the method with `var`, it would only be accessible within the file, and cannot be called from the client.

```
var yourmethod = function() {
    ...
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
function yourmethod() { 
    ...
}
```

Or you can define it so any of your server script can use it:

```
yourmethod = function() {
    ....
}
```

If you mean you want a RPC method call that is accessible only from the javascript code, but not from the javascript console in chrome this isn't possible. This is because the idea behind meteor is **all** RPCs from the client are not trusted & there is no way to distinguish whether it came from the console or not. You can use meteor user authentication or [Collection.allow](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) or [Collection.deny](http://docs.meteor.com/#deny) methods to prevent any unauthorized changes this way.

Comment: Meteor 'allow' and 'deny' restrict access directly from the client. Meteor methods are ran on the server - although called from the client, therefore bypassing this layer of protection. Does this mean that - security wise - CRUD operations are not to be called inside a Meteor method?

Comment: In a Meteor method the Allow/Deny don't apply because the method is run on the server.

Comment: That was the intention of my question. To rephrase: what is the safe way to perform CRUD operations on the server, without granting client access?

Answer (score 3):

I made a private method by checking this.connection to be null.

Ref: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_connection

Ex.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'serverCallOnlyFunc': function() {
    if (this.connection === null) {
      //do something
    } else {
      throw(new Meteor.Error(500, 'Permission denied!'));
    }
  }
});
```